# How prevent "Pick an Account" interactive workflow when using Connect-AzAccount

Tags: azure, powershell, authentication

**Short version:** Is there any "pre" pick method in the script, to utilize it in the scenario when *authentication is already remembered in previous interactions*, and only the "pick" functionality should be done?

**Context**

I have multiple MS Accounts for each one there are one or more subscription.
I use PowerShell 7 scripts (Az Module) to automate repeated tasks. Some scripts use one account, others scripts use other account, and I use the all scripts in daily bases. Although Az module remembers which was *last* account in `Connect-AzAccount`, unfortunately, in the ad-hoc next script, there is a need to use an other account.

I use Connect-AzAccount in the scripts which pops up the browser dialog. In the browser I can pick the appropriate account, from the multiple offered accounts, what were remembered in the previous logins.

The credentials for the accounts are **remembered** (btw, I have no idea *where*, because those credentials are definitely do not show up in the Credential Manager) Anyway, the point is that I do not have to (re)authenticate myself which is fine.

**Question**

Because the role of interaction this scenario is only to pick an account (and not the authentication itself) I would like to do it without user interaction. I've examined the available switches of `Connect-AzAccount` neither seems to be work, (-AccountId or -TenandId, etc) for different reasons

I would not like to use other credential mechanism, I mean I would like to utilize those credentials what are exist and allows this workflow, but blocks the automation with the "Pick an Account" browser interaction.

Answer (score 1):

**Short Answer :**

The Connect-AzAccount don't have internal mechanism to achieve that.

**Long Answer :**

However, you could simulate the login flow at the powershell.

When You run `Connect-AzAccount`

Internally, there is a browser session opened with the below URL.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=https://management.core.windows.net//.default openid profile offline_access&response_type=code&client_id=1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8400/&x-client-SKU=MSAL.Desktop&x-client-Ver=4.21.0.0&x-client-CPU=x64&x-client-OS=Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19042.0&prompt=select_account
```

If you closely look, `prompt = select_account`

You could directly hit the below URL with powershell

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?scope=https://management.core.windows.net//.default openid profile offline_access&response_type=code&client_id=1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8400/&x-client-SKU=MSAL.Desktop&x-client-Ver=4.21.0.0&x-client-CPU=x64&x-client-OS=Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19042.0&login_hint=<USERNAME@DOMAIN.COM>
```

You could use the below IE Automation Object from shell to achieve it.

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("google.co.in")
$ie.navigate("<The above url>")
$ie.visible = $true
```

This will indirectly give you the code - you will have perform the authentication against the required tenant.

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

With required parameters in the POST body

```
client_id=1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2&client_info=1&scope=https://management.core.windows.net//.default offline_access openid profile&grant_type=authorization_code&code=
<Code>
```

you could do `invoke-webrequest`

You will be able to get the access token as a response that you have obtained from here

With the Access token - You will be able to do the `connect-azaccount -Accesstoken <TOKEN`>

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow

**Note :**

The credentials are remembered by the IE when you login the first time.

Comment: Many thx. I am amazed how deep you investigated into this. I am going to try this with Chrome or Edge. IE is uninstalled in my Win 10